# entities.SaveChanges() not saving to db

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying a simple program in EF to add a player from a gridview to a team. The code seems to work until the savechanges part. Judging by other posts, it's a problem with my code but I can't see what.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedIndex);
    int pId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[v].Value);
    chosenPlayer = entities.Players.Find(pId);
    int noPlayers = myTeam.Players.Count();

    if (noPlayers < 5)
    {
        myTeam.Players.Add(chosenPlayer);
    }
    entities.SaveChanges();
    RefreshGrid();
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  Or are you not *making* any changes to data in the database?  You grab an entity into `chosenPlayer` but you don't make any changes to it.  What do you expect `SaveChanges()` to persist to the database?

Comment: Where does `myTeam` come from?

Comment: The database was generated by the EF model.
Team              Player
ID                ID 
Name              Name

Team myTeam = new Team(); //Declared before the PageLoad

The idea is that you add chosenPlayer to myTeam.

Comment: Do you mean your changes are not saved or there have some exceptions triggered?

Comment: They are not being saved. In debugging mode, under entities there's an X beside local with the message 'The function evaluation requires all threads to run'. When I switch it on manually, it defaults back to the X.